# Regular Expression to match a String

Tags: regex

Can you please help to derive a regular expression that matches the bold-italics portion of below string? Characters in `X` will change. This information is from a log file. I need to remove all the timestamps from the log file.

***[6/14/12 18:10:XX:XX CDT] 000001234*** XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Please improve your question by including whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @CodeGnome seems clear enough! though normally i'd have thought times are more liek 18:10:XX.XX  (that last thing a dot rather than a colon.. for milliseconds but anyway)

Comment: @TimPote he's just asking for a regular expression, that makes sense independent of programming language and requires no programming code at all

Comment: @barlop I disagree entirely.  sed, egrep, perl, bash, java, python, etc. all have drastically different syntaxes and constructs.  I need to know what he intends to use in order to know what features he has available.

Comment: @TimPote  I know there's BRE, ERE and PCRE.. PCRE with more constructs than ERE, though that's not differences in programming language. There may be very fine differences between languages like perhaps some may not support PCRE.. but for this at least, it can be written in like ERE.. pretty supported..  can do [0-9] No need to use \d for example. This for example from bash looks very standard http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html#sect_04_01_02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, in Perl, assuming that the X's are alphanumeric:

```
/\[6/14/12\s18:10:\w{2}:\w{2}\sCDT\]\s000001234/
```

If you also want to capture the varying characters, you can put them in parentheses, then use backreferences:

```
/\[6/14/12\s18:10:(\w{2}):(\w{2})\sCDT\]\s000001234/
```

Other languages similar with slight variations in syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Example in Python

```
>>> import re
>>> test = '[6/14/12 18:10:XX:XX CDT] 000001234'
>>> print re.findall(r'\[6/14/12 18:10:..:.. CDT\] 000001234', test)
['[6/14/12 18:10:XX:XX CDT] 000001234']
```

The `.` matches every character, so we have 4 dots to match the `XX:XX` part. Also, the `[` and `]` are special characters within regular expressions so we need  to escape those.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one, tested in grep, it's within the quotes. Should work quite universally. Would work with grep -E too as it doesn't use any advanced regex features.

```
C:\>echo [6/14/12 18:10:46:XX CDT] 000001234 | grep -P "\[6/14/12 18:10:([0-9]|[
0-9][0-9]|XX):([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|XX) CDT\] 000001234"
[6/14/12 18:10:46:XX CDT] 000001234

C:\>
```

so

```
\[6/14/12 18:10:([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|XX):([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|XX) CDT\] 000001234
```